# How to make super fast filtering NSArray operation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, json, core-data

I have a situation, i need to create relationships in core data for 1000 checkpoints objects to 4000 routeSequence objects, i have JSON **RouteSequence** entity like this:

```
{
    "checkpoint_id": 506,
    "hash": "f3ab72c1cb65ce73334d4fb257f7ca3d",
    "is_end": true,
    "is_forward_direction": true,
    "next_checkpoint_id": 509,
    "order": 0,
    "path": [
            "65.594608 57.112931",
            "65.591262 57.112920",
            "65.590060 57.112888",
            "65.589605 57.112841",
            "65.589151 57.112748",
            "65.588543 57.112388",
            "65.588526 57.112383",
            "65.588047 57.112037"
    ],
    "route_id": 66
},
{
    "checkpoint_id": 28,
    "hash": "512f248f72e8d46e6a56774e974ea79b",
    "is_end": true,
    "is_forward_direction": true,
    "next_checkpoint_id": 729,
    "order": 0,
    "path": [
            "65.635648 57.113168",
            "65.634405 57.113396",
            "65.634186 57.113431",
            "65.633957 57.113427",
            "65.633744 57.113383",
            "65.633567 57.113305",
            "65.633208 57.113091",
            "65.631777 57.113354"
    ],
    "route_id": 10
},
```

and **Checkpoints** entity like this

```
{
    "city_id": 1,
    "code_number": "03283",
    "description": "---",
    "hash": "eb6b56b6ca2339e6bcd2e31df74de10b",
    "id": 3396,
    "lat": 57.2015298151631,
    "lon": 65.3598978059826,
    "name": "\"Астра\"",
    "routes_ids": [
            61
    ]
},
{
    "city_id": 1,
    "code_number": "03282",
    "description": "---",
    "hash": "68f2a82d3745413662fed4c30eab6b49",
    "id": 3397,
    "lat": 57.20036829793,
    "lon": 65.3599455633935,
    "name": "\"Астра\"",
    "routes_ids": [
            61
    ]
},
```

What i need to do? I need to create relationship beetween RouteSequence.checkpoint_id == Checkpoint.id
At the moment of creating relationship i have already create object from this json. At now this operation takes over 15 seconds. Our data updating daily and it inadmissible to wait for launch application every morning for 15 seconds.

```
NSArray *checkpoints = [delegate.writerManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:[NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Checkpoint"] error:&error];
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *routeSequences = [[[delegate.writerManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:[NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"RouteSequence"] error:&error] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"checkpointID" ascending:YES]]] mutableCopy];
        for (Checkpoint *checkpoint in checkpoints) {
            NSLog(@"%i", routeSequences.count);
            array = [routeSequences filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"checkpointID == %@", checkpoint.id]];
            [checkpoint addRouteSequences:[NSSet setWithArray:array]];
            [routeSequences removeObjectsInArray:array];
        }
```

For now temporary solution is to make this operation in background, but we don't want that, we want to make things better, so question - how to speed up this operation. Maybe we can to this in clean C?

Comment: It's a 1000 checkpoints and 4000 sequence routes, so obviously it needs some amount of time in seconds to complete those operations, but if you want you can speed up the operation by doing those all operations on different thread

Comment: this is core data context objects, so operations on them can be only in one thread(of course, i can mistake). I've tried this. I thought to split array to process on different threads

Comment: I've tried before core data context objects operations in different thread, when I wanted to sync my app at the starting of application and it was working really fine. Main thing is you can't split up your core data operations in different threads specially when it's bound by relationships, but you can process all those operation in one thread, which won't be main UI thread or Background thread. This is the way how you can achieve it.

Comment: Can you sort both the RouteSequence and Checkpoint arrays by checkpoint id? Then as you iterate over the Checkpoint array, the associated RouteSequences will all be grouped together and they will all be near the front of the RouteSequence array. You can iterate over RouteSequences until you find an id greater than the current checkpoint id and then stop looking at routes and continue to next checkpoint.

Comment: this all i already achieved, my application for now already launching without waiting this operation, but there is danger, that the user will launch view, which have data that depends on this operations, so the app will exit with error

Comment: does someone used predicateWithBlock? I can't find example of using this method
ama1111 - great idea. Already checked this, the speed increased for 2 seconds)) For now this is completes with 11 seconds)))